# How to Duplicate current `Family Type` and update it's parameters

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We are using Autodesk's Forge (or Platform Service), more specifically, the `Design Automation` where we run scripts on our files in the cloud.

We are looking into ways to import a "Type Catalog" (which is a ".txt" file) into the opened ".rfa" file using Design Automation. One possible way is to parse the `.txt` file and then `Duplicate` the current/opened `Family Type` and after that update the parameters in the Duplicated Family Type with values from the txt file and lastly set the `CurrentFamilyType` to the new Family Type.

Since we can only use "Autodesk.Revit.DB;" (No UI allowed), we couldn't figure out how to `Duplicate` the current `Family Type` and to achieve the aforementioned task. Normally, using the Revit app, we could just select `Create -> Family Types -> New Type` and create a new family type, or we could go `Insert -> Import Family Types` and then select the .txt file and import the new type, but as I said, without UI, that's not possible, so we have to work around this with the possible solution I mentioned earlier.

Any information or example on how we could achieve the result we want would be greatly appreciated!

*The `.txt` file is located inside the `AppBundle` with the rest of the files we use in `Design Automation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

1. Open the family document.
2. Access [Document.FamilyManager](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/478fde66-c9f0-86b5-204a-c95f18b69ca1.htm).
3. Call [FamilyManager.NewType()](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/b46e98b1-54a1-7e04-66b7-a35efe5bc3f8.htm).
4. Change the [FamilyManager.CurrentType](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/3d37cd81-48ba-4011-82bc-dbb7ae14b270.htm).
5. Parse and apply your text file.

I would try this locally before sending it to design automation. Learn how to [Debug Revit plugin locally](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-debug-revit-plugin-locally).

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the closely related Revit API forum discussion on [Importing Type Catalog .txt into .rfa at runtime](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/importing-type-catalog-txt-into-rfa-at-runtime/m-p/12125015). It includes sample code verified to work in both the .NET desktop and the APS Design Automation APIs.